# How to move an item from a JSON object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have two json objects:

```
open_positions = [{\"id\":83,\"position\":0},{\"id\":82,\"position\":1},{\"id\":79,\"position\":2}]

done_positions = [{\"id\":85,\"position\":0},{\"id\":84,\"position\":1}]
```

How can I select an item from open_positions given an ID and move it to the top of done_positions?

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual code? What you have is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript.

Comment: It's posted via rails, in the rails log here is an example of how it looks: Parameters: { "list_items"=>{"open_positions"=>"[{\"id\":83,\"position\":0},{\"id\":82,\"position\":1}]", "done_positions"=>"[{\"id\":85,\"position\":0},{\"id\":84,\"position\":1}]"}

Answer (score 2):

```
open_positions = [{"id":83,"position":0},{"id":82,"position":1},{"id":79,"position":2}];

done_positions = [{"id":85,"position":0},{"id":84,"position":1}];

function move_to_done(id){
  for(var pos in open_positions){
    if(open_positions[pos].id == id){
      done_positions.push(open_positions[pos]);
      delete open_positions[pos];
    }
  }
}

move_to_done(83);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to parse the JSON, you can switch id's with this function.

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYED5/1/

```
function change( id ) {
    var re = new RegExp( "(,)?\\{\\\"id\\\"\\:" + id + "\\,\\\"position\\\"\\:[0-9]*\\}(,)?" );
    var match = open.match( re );
    done = done.replace( "]", "," + ( match ? match[0] : "" ) + "]" ).replace( ",,", "," ).replace( ",]", "]" );
    open = open.replace( re, "" ).replace( "}{", "},{" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open_positions = [{"id":83,"position":0},{"id":82,"position":1},{"id":79,"position":2}];
done_positions = [{"id":85,"position":0},{"id":84,"position":1}];

id = 82;

for(key in open_positions){
    if(open_positions[key].id === id){
        myObj = open_positions[key];
    }
}

newObj = new Object();
newObj[0] = myObj;
for(key in done_positions){
    newObj[key+1] = done_positions[key];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var open_positions = [{"id":83,"position":0},{"id":82,"position":1},{"id":79,"position":2}];
var done_positions = [{"id":85,"position":0},{"id":84,"position":1}];

for(var index in open_positions){ 
    if(open_positions[index]["id"]=="83"){
        done_positions.unshift(open_positions[index])
        open_positions.splice(index,1)
    }
}
```

Also probably there is no need for the propierty "position" because is the same index.